# jmeter JSON Extractor failed to when to process [

Tags: json, jmeter

I am having problem of extracting the json value when the data has a leading [.  Ex: [{"userID":"12"}]

I used "jp@gc - Dummy Sampler" to mock a test json data and when removed the leading [ and trailing ], the JSON Extractor seems to be able to read the json.  Ex: {"userID":"12"}

A leading [ is valid JSON format; therefore, I am not sure if my assumption is correct.  Is my finding sounds correct?  If yes, what is the best way for me to remove the leading and trailing [].

thanks

Answer (score 0):

"[]" means it's an array.

So to extract 12 you would use:

> [0].userID

An alternative is to use:

> $..userID

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..` - a deep scan operator in order to get the values from JSON no matter how many nested levels deep they are:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Deep Scan]

You may also find [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article useful as it contains several most frequently required examples of working with JSON Path Extractor